# Is it possible to use label spreading scikit algorithm on edgelist?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a network edgelist and I want to use the Label Spreading/Label Propagation algorithm from scikit-learn. I have a set of nodes that are labeled and want to spread the labels on the unlabeled portion of the network. I can generate the adjacency matrix or confusion matrix if needed.

Can someone point me in the right direction using scikit?  The documentation seems so limited in what I can do with it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: People landing on this page may want to check out this answer https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/55720/77683.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Label Spreading you should follow these steps:
1. create a vector of labels (y), where all the unlabeled instances are set to -1.
2. fit the model using your feature data (X) and y.
3. create predict_entropies vector using stats.distributions.entropy(*yourmodelname*.label_distributions_.T)
4. create an uncertainty index by sorting the predict_entropies vector.
5. send the samples of lowest certainty for label query.

I hope this framework will help you get started.